# For loop to create list of vectors of varying length

Tags: r, list, for-loop

> For loop to create list of vectors of varying length.

I created this dataframe

```
set.seed = 1
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)
z <- rexp(10)
w <- sample(1:100, 10)
tb <- tibble(x,y,z,w)
```

I would like to create a list containing the ranges of the variables in the table.

This is what I tried.

```
L <- length(names(tb))
names <- vector("list",L)
for (i in 1:L){
  names[i] <- range(tb[i])
}
```

I created a list of length 4, I tried to use the for loop above to get the ranges, However it only takes the minimum of each range and gives this error

> Warning message:
> In names[1] <- x :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

I believe I need to pre allocate a list of vectors, all of which are length 2 inside the list, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: It's a list, so you need a double bracket: `names[[i]] <- range(tb[i])`. Or skip the loop and use `lapply`: `names <- lapply(tb, range)`.

Comment: `set.seed = 1` is assigning a local variable named the same as a necessary and useful R function, but unless you want to use the _variable_ `set.seed` in some mathematical sense, this code is doing nothing for you. If you want reproducibility, use the _function_ instead: `set.seed(1)`.